# VBA Selenium - return all elements with specific attribute

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome

I'm using Selenium in Excel VBA to scrape some websites. I'm hoping to find all elements on a webpage which look similar to the snippet below:

`<div class="outcomeName_f18x6kvm" data-automation-id="racecard-outcome-name"><span class="size14_f7opyze Endeavour_fhudrb0 medium_f1wf24vo">1. The Running Man</span><span class="size11_fwt0xu4 Endeavour_fhudrb0 light_f2noysy">&nbsp;(5)</span></div>`

In particular, I'm hoping to find all elements which contain the attribute `data-automation-id` and then filter by elements which have `racecard-outcome-name` as this attribute, but this should be easy once I can return all elements with this attribute.

Currently I'm using something similar to

`table = bot.FindElementsBy.Attribute("data-automation-id")`
but I know this is the incorrect use of this operator. Please let me know if you can point me in thr right direction.

Comment: `bot.FindElementsByCss("[data-automation-id]")`    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to QHarr for providing a helpful comment. I ended up implementing the following solution to find elements where the `data-automation-id` had been tagged `racecard-outcome-name`:

```
    Set table = bot.FindElementsByCss("[data-automation-id]")
    
    Dim i As Integer, tableCount As Integer
    tableCount = table.count
    For i = 1 To table.count
        If table(i).Attribute("data-automation-id") = "racecard-outcome-name" Then
            MsgBox table(i).Text
        End If
    Next i
```